# React event handling between Child and Parent Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and couldn't find anything on stack overflow for this. I can't call the event handler from the parent component. *However* If I copy and paste what's inside of `ZipSearchField`, into the `App` parent component (and change the props to this) it works as expected. Code below:

If it's not clear, I want to handle the change in the parent component but can't seem to do so. It never gets called and there is no error anywhere.

```
function ZipSearchField(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container-search-bar">
    <form>
      <label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Try 11223..." onChange={props.handleChange}/>
      </label>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    console.log("things changed")
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">
            <h2>Zip Code Search</h2>
          </div>
          <ZipSearchField onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, thank you!

Comment: onChange={props.handleChange} should be onChange={props.onChange} in the ZipSearchField  component

Comment: that was it, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered in the comments By Sudhakar RS.

Inside of the child component, you don't call the function but you link the onChange hook to the parent's onChange hook.

So child looks like this:

```
function ZipSearchField(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container-search-bar">
    <form>
      <label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Try 11223..." onChange={props.onChange}/>
      </label>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Thank you!